# c# winforms одновременно вставить в базу данных несколько запись

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

десткоп приложение для склада, из datagridview сделал корзину покупок, тоесть из базу данных продуктов добавляю в корзину продукт, после через цикл вставляю эти данные в базу данных. нужно для всех записей сделать один ID, тоесть пытаюсь сделать InvoiceID. 10 товаров вставляю в базу - для всех этих товаров один InvoiceID.

```
    public ExportProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadAllProductList();
        //  dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        dt.Columns.Add("qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("price");
        dt.Columns.Add("category");
        dt.Columns.Add("company");
        dt.Columns.Add("otdel");
        dt.Columns.Add("date");
    }

 private void button2Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           var Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection; 

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                        {
                    command.CommandText = @"insert into export values(@name, @qty, @price, @category, @company, @otdel)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", row.Cells["name"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells["qty"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row.Cells["price"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", row.Cells["category"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", row.Cells["company"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otdel", row.Cells["otdel"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", row.Cells["date"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                   
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    LabelInfo.Text = "Successfuly saved!";
                }
        }
        
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
    }
```

добавление в корзину товаров

```
       private void btnAddToOrderList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        row = dt.NewRow();
      //  row["id"] = IdTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["name"] = NameTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["qty"] = QtyTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["price"] = PriceTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["category"] = CategoryTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["company"] = CompanyTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["otdel"] = OtdelTextbox.Text.ToString();
        row["date"] = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
     //   IdTextbox.Text = "";
        NameTextbox.Text ="";
        QtyTextbox.Text = "";
        PriceTextbox.Text = "";
        CategoryTextbox.Text = "";
        CompanyTextbox.Text = "";
        OtdelTextbox.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Text = "";

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что не работает?

Comment: @Aarnihauta, могу ли сгенерировать для 3 записей в базе один ID-ник ? . это нужно чтоб составить Invoice счет, можно было бы ручной вводит, а можно  как-то автоматический сгенерировать ?

Comment: Не можете. Id - уникальный элемент записи в таблице, можете использовать foreign key создав новую таблицу под вашу задачу состоящую из `UniqueId`, `ForeignId` и нужные Вам поля

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужно внести в БД несколько записей для того, чтобы сформировать заказ.
Для этого вам следует создать две таблицы:
Orders (id, user_id, etc... ) - тут содержится информация о заказе, не о товарах.
OrderItems (id, order_id, item_id), где id - идентификатор записи, order_id - идентификатор заказа, а item_id - идентификатор товара в заказе.
Думаю, так вы решите свою проблему.
Если дело не в этом, исправьте меня.

Comment: @Aarnihauta,  тоесть нужно вводит вручную ?  хм. не подскажите как минусовать запись одной таблицы при добавлений в другую таблицу ?  тоесть в таблице продукты есть 4 коробки печенья , при переносе в таблицу заказов 2 коробки печенья нужно минусовать из таблицу продуктов 2 коробки

Comment: @Danila, возможно ваша идея правильная , я хотел бы сделать корзинку из datagridview. туда переносить товары , и добавлять в таблицу заказов под одним ID-номером, чтоб понят какие товары были проданный в определенное время конкретному покупателю. еще проблема в том , нужно минусовать из продуктов проданные товары

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я хотел бы сделать корзинку из datagridview. туда переносить товары , и добавлять в таблицу заказов под одним ID-номером, чтоб понят какие

Да, всё верно, вам следует добавить две таблицы:

1. Orders (id, user_id, etc... ) - тут содержится информация о заказе, не о товарах.
2. OrderItems (id, order_id, item_id), где id - идентификатор записи, order_id - идентификатор заказа, а item_id - идентификатор товара в заказе.

> товары были проданный в определенное время конкретному покупателю.

Здесь вам стоит добавить столбец с datetime в таблицу Orders.

> еще проблема в том , нужно минусовать из продуктов проданные товары

Здесь вам нужно сформировать запрос DELETE к таблице вашей БД, в которой вы хотите удалить записи.

Comment: если не сложно можете показать пример, допустим есть столбец qty  в таблице product,